# C# using SqliteCommand

Tags: c#, sqlite

Is it some manuals that describing how often `SqliteCommand` can be used. And what is situation that needed to be avoid?

What dangerous can contains this code with many functions?

```
private void UpgradeDataBaseEmptyColumn()
{
    var connection = GetConnection();
    {
        AddColumnIsEmpty(connection);
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                ProcessIsEmptyColumn(connection);
            });
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

function `AddColumnIsEmpty`

```
private void AddColumnIsEmpty(SQLiteConnection connection)
{
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
    {
        //SOmething done
    }
}
```

function `ProcessIsEmptyColumn`

```
public void ProcessIsEmptyColumn(SQLiteConnection connection)
{
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
    {
        foreach (var item in getEmptyItemsNotUpdated(connection))
        {
            using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                //Something doe
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

function `getEmptyItemsNotUpdated`

```
private List<int> getEmptyItemsNotUpdated(SQLiteConnection connection)
{
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
    {
        //return idToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking? An application can use millions (and more) of command objects to query a database across a single execution. Or are you asking about reusing instances? If so: don't. Connection pooling means there is no benefit to keeping connection objects alive; and changing connection objects for a command object would be confusing.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Right now it is unclear what exactly are you asking.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, you are right the question is to broad. I post some example, Maybe it's became better.

Comment: @Richard, you are right the question is too broad. I post some example, Maybe it's became better.

Comment: What **specifically** is the question?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, is there any dangerous of using command's in such way like in example?

Comment: If you mean the thread you spin up, then no, you should not do that. SqlConnection is not threadsafe.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, can you post answer how it should be in your opinion?

Comment: Don't spin up a thread? Or let the thread manage its own connection.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, and what about using(command ...) is it normal way?

Comment: The `using` statements looks correct to me. You should dispose all objects that implement `IDisposable` when you're done with them *as a rule* (not as a law but it is important to know why the rule exists and the consequences of breaking it before you can safely break it).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen,Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that SQLiteConnection instance is not guaranteed to be **thread**
>   **safe**. You should **avoid** using the same SQLiteConnection in several
>   threads at the same time. It is recommended to open a new connection
>   per thread and to close it when the work is done. Actually,
>   connections will not be created/disposed every time with the
>   Pooling=true; connection string option - connections will be stored at
>   connection pool. This boosts performance greatly.

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *can* re-use commands, but it is often awkward to do so, as you need to clear the parameters, change the command-text, etc. By the time you've done all that, it is usually easier to just start with a clean object. And since most methods should only do one thing, it is rare that you'd find a scenario where you need multiple.

The main time commands are re-used is when you want to issue the same command lots of times successively, perhaps only varying the parameter values between calls. Depending on the ADO.NET provider, re-using commands might make a big difference (improving performance), or it might make virtually no difference.